# TSQL, time difference between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the difference in minutes between two dates, lets say:

> **from** 
>   2/23/2017 17:00:00 pm. 
>  **until** 
>  2/24/2017 02:00:00 am.

Which would be the best approach?

I figured to do something like:

```
SELECT datediff (minute, START, END) from TIME;
```

But as a result I get:

-900 minutes.

My TIME table only has those columns (ID_TIME, START, END), and the date (MM/DD/YYYY) is not included, but only the START and END hours.

**UPDATE:**
Maybe is not the correct way to do it, but,  I altered the `-900` with a simple arithmetic operation:

> (((-900)*-1)-360) = 540.

This was my code:
`$time2=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH);
    echo "time 2: ".((($time2[0])*-1)-360)."<br>";` 
If there's a way to do it without an arithmetic operation I would be grateful

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following and got 540.

```
declare @Start datetime
declare @End datetime
set @Start = '2017-2-23 17:00:00'
set @End = '2017-2-24 2:00:00'

select datediff(minute, @Start, @End)
```

Perhaps it would be useful to also print out the Start and End dates?

```
SELECT datediff (minute, START, END), START, END from TIME;
```

Comment: That works great, although I've got another problem, the dates are not defined in the table, but only the START and END times, I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

What data types are you using the contain the datetime info in your table? In the examples below you can see how your approach is correct and I received the result 540 in all of these examples.

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP_TIME (START_DATE VARCHAR(35), END_DATE VARCHAR(35))

INSERT INTO #TMP_TIME
SELECT '2/23/2017 17:00:00 pm','2/24/2017 02:00:00 am'

Select DATEDIFF(minute,START_DATE,END_DATE ) FROM #TMP_TIME
Select DATEDIFF(mi,START_DATE,END_DATE ) FROM #TMP_TIME


CREATE TABLE #TMP_TIME2 (START_DATE DATETIME, END_DATE DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #TMP_TIME2
SELECT '2/23/2017 17:00:00','2/24/2017 02:00:00'

Select DATEDIFF(minute,START_DATE,END_DATE ) FROM #TMP_TIME2
Select DATEDIFF(mi,START_DATE,END_DATE ) FROM #TMP_TIME2
```

Comment: the START and END have a TIME(7) type.
I updated some information, I can't input the **MM/DD/YYYY** into the table, only the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
declare @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime
set @startdate='2/23/2017 17:00:00 pm' 
set @enddate= '2/24/2017 02:00:00 am'

select datediff(ss,@startdate,@enddate)/60
```